# What does this java code do?

Tags: java, android, class, object

I just came across some syntax i've never seen before, and because it's quite hard to find answers on Google, i decided to ask a question.
The statement in question is:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

I know that the code is creating an object "editText" of the EditText class, but i've never seen the code after the equal sign before.
My best guess is that's it's running the method findViewById(), and that this message is present in the EditText class, which is why the EditText in the parentheses is necessary?

I know i probably ought to know this syntax by now, as i just finished my first java course at CS college, but unfortunately we were never introduced to something like this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html is the first answer here for `findViewById`, and it's worth a read if you want to get into android development.

Comment: this is an android syntax of finding elements that have been declared in the xml file. I sugguest you go through developer.android.com in order to learn android programming, atleast so that you would get familiar with this syntax.

Comment: I think EditText is a class and findViewbyId must return something that need to be casted to EditText class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typecast, forcing the compiler to assume that the result returned by the function `findViewById` is an `EditText` object.

If it is of another type, you'd get a runtime error.

[Here's the offical docs on the subject.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and link to documentation :)

Comment: I would add that this only works if EditText is a subclass of View, which is the type returned by findViewById; otherwise the compiler will throw an error, since it knows the type returned by the method.  And another way to put "forcing the compiler to assume that" would be "telling the compiler to treat"

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById` returns a `View`, so

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

will throw a compile exception telling you that you cannot assign a `View` to an `EditText` variable.

`(EditText)` is casting `View` type to `EditText`, in other words, you tell the compiler that it's safe to assign the result of `findViewById` to the `EditText`, as you expect that `edit_message` view is actually an `EditText` object.

Finally, if you're 'lying' to the compiler and `edit_message` is not an `EditText`, you'll be able to compile and run, but you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

It is used for creating textbox in which you can type your query, in this code findviewbyid is an method which return an object while (EditText) is used for casting and as here the returned object is of type edittext thats why we are save in an variable edittext of type EDITTEXT.